# Issue with OpenMP thread execution and threadprivate variable

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, fortran90

I have used 8 threads for 8 loops. I have used 'print' to see how the parallel code works. The 0 thread creates problems!I have showed in the attached diagram (please check the attached link below) how the parallel works. I have used threadprivate but it turned out that thread 0 can not get any private threadsafe variables.

I have tried with modules as well and got same results! 
Any idea why the code acts this way? I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks!

```
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO
  do nb=m3+1, m3a, 2
  60 icall=nb
  65 iad=idint(a(icall))    
  if(iad.eq.0) goto 100     
  call ford(a(iad),servo)      
  if(.not.dflag) goto 80  
  atemp=dble(nemc)
  nemc=iad
  a(icall)=a(iad+6)
  a(iad+6) = atemp
  dflag=.false.
  goto 65    
  80 icall=iad+6     
  goto 65
  100 continue
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

  subroutine FORD(i,j)
  dimension zl(3),zg(3)
  common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,
   .               b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
  common /root/ root1,root2
  !$OMP threadprivate (/ellip/,/root/)
  CALL CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
  return
  end subroutine

  SUBROUTINE CONDACT(genflg,lapflg)
  common /ellip/ b1,c1,f1,g1,h1,d1,b2,c2,f2,g2,h2,p2,q2,r2,d2
  !$OMP threadprivate (/ellip/)
  RETURN
  END
```

[image]

Comment: In the absence of declarations not shown, you have lots of shared variables in the body of the do loop (`icall`, `iad`, etc...).  You need to fix that.

Comment: Please reconsider coding like this. Implicit typing, `common` blocks, and even `goto` are nothing but trouble.

Comment: As written elsewhere, global variables are a bad idea for parallel execution, as you found out, it does not matter, wether the global variable is a module variable or a common block entity. As pointed out in my answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146/577108 you probably should use derived data types and pass it around. However, it is still somewhat unclear to me, what your actually algorithm is. Is the result of your ford call found in servo or in one of the common blocks? Right now, it is even unclear wether this is parallelizable at all.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at just the first few lines you have major problems.

```
   do nb=m3+1, m3a, 2
```

This part is fine, each thread will have a private copy of `nb` properly initialized.

```
60   icall=nb
```

This is a problem.  `icall` is shared and each thread will write its private value of `nb` into the shared.  Threads run concurrently and the order and timing is non-determanistic so the value of `icall` in each thread cannot be known ahead of time.

```
65   iad=idint(a(icall))
```

Now we use `icall` to calculate a value to store in the shared variable `iad`.  What are the problems?  The value of `icall` may not be the same as in the previous line if another thread wrote to it between this thread's execution.  The value of `iad` is being clobbered by each thread.

```
     if(iad.eq.0) goto 100     
     call ford(a(iad),servo)
```

These lines have the same problems as above.  The value of `iad` may not be the same as above and it may not be the same between these two lines depending on the execution of the other threads.

```
     if(.not.dflag) goto 80
```

The variable `dflag` has not been initialized at this point.

To fix these problems you need to declare `icall` and `iad` as private with

```
!$omp parallel do private(icall,iad)
```

You should also initialize `dflag` before you use it.

These first errors are probably responsible for a large chunk of your problem but may not fix everything.  You have architected very complex (hard to maintain) thread interaction and your code is full of bad practices (implicit variables, liberal use of `goto`) which make this code hard to follow.

Comment: +1 for the scolding delivered in your last paragraph -- implicit lots, multiple threads, shared memory, common blocks, gotos -- it's going to end in tears.

Comment: I second the comment from Mark. OpenMP and typical Fortran 77 or 66 is not a happy mix.