# Value not passing to subroutine using a common block

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm trying to pass a parameter between a Fortran main program and a subroutine.  However for some reason a different value is obtained in the subroutine. I am using common blocks.

```
program main
nzcur=1
write(*.*)"nzcur in main",nzcur

call hit

subroutine hit
common/part/nzcur
write(*,*)"nzcur in hit",nzcur; pause
end

end program
```

I would expect `nzcur=1` but I get `nzcur=0`.

I think it could be a data type mismatch as I do not define it, only as a common block.

Comment: *I am using common blocks*  Noooohhhhhhh !  Just don't.  Find a basic Fortran tutorial written sometime in the last 40 years and learn how to pass arguments to, and from, subroutines.  You should find useful material in other questions and answers on this site too.

Comment: For the good of our children, just say 'Nooooohhhh' to `COMMON` block.  It is fraught with perils as you have found.  If you do not want to use arguments to a subroutine (for some unknown reason), then use `MODULE`.

Comment: Also pause should nit have been used in about the last 40 years. And please show the program you are actually trying, or a cut down version if it is a bit long - the above won't compile under any version of Fortran.

Comment: There should either be a contains before the `subroutine` or the subroutine must come after the `end program` otherwise the program simply cannot compile. If you have a problem with any code and ask on this site, always show a [mcve]. It shall be an actual code that one can try to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have removed my common blocks and am now trying to use modules. I was using common blocks because that is what the book I am using suggested.  I now get the following error:

    ` error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [VARIABLES] `
    

The code is:

    
`module variables
real(8) nzcur
save
end module variables

program main
use variables
nzcur=1
call hit
end program main

contains
subroutine hit
use variables
write(*,*)nzcur
end`

Comment: Update (can't edit previous comment: Managed to get it to work with modules! Just needed to fix up the syntax. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For passing data between routines try to learn how to use argument lists, look at the link at the end of francescalus' answer - this is the best way, modules for passing data is little better than common blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the correct learning response to this question is to avoid using common blocks to have access to variables from other scopes.  In writing code in the modern era there are far better ways (more later).

Fortunately, however, we can look at this question in terms of "how do I understand what is happening with this common block?".  Such a question is useful to those unfortunate programmers trying to understand old (or badly written new) code.

In considering the program of the question one should note that several corrections are required to have compilable code (with different possible approaches).  The errors there are not directly relevant to the discussion.

In the subroutine

```
subroutine hit
common/part/nzcur
write(*,*)"nzcur in hit",nzcur; pause
end
```

we have a named common block called `part`, with one numeric storage unit which contains the integer variable `nzcur` (thanks to implicit typing).

In the question there is clearly the expectation that the variable `nzcur` in this common block accesses some other variable called `nzcur` and that this other variable is the one in the main program called `nzcur`.  This is not correct.

`nzcur` in the subroutine is associated only with the first numeric storage unit of any other common block named `part`.  The association is not based on named or location in the common block definition.

In the program of the question, there is no other common block called `part`; `nzcur` of the subroutine is not associated with anything else.  It is certainly not associated with a variable not in a common block.

Because of this lack of association, the variable is not defined by the time the write statement references it.  Again, the definition of the variable in the main program does not affect the definition of the local variable in the subroutine.

To "correct" the association, it will be necessary to put the variable `nzcur` of the main program in the correct location in a common block named `part` (in the main program).

---

To answer the question of "how do I set the value of `nzcur` in the subroutine without using common blocks?", refer to other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146/3157076).