# Repeatedly used 2D array in a Fortran 90 subroutine

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran 90 program that is of the structure shown below. The step `compute the 2D array myMatrix(1:N,1:N)` in the `subroutinne A` is expensive. It depends only on the global variable `N` and it needs to be computed only once; the "other steps" in the subroutine will not change the value of myMatrix. Currently, `myMatrix` will be calculated whenever the subroutine is called.

Is there a way to write the program in a way that the 2D array `myMatrix` is calculated only once?

```
module constants
    integer :: N
end module constans

module A_module
use constants
contains
    subroutine A
    ! compute the 2D real array myMatrix(1:N,1:N)
    ! other steps that use myMatrix
    end subroutine A
end module A_module

program main
    use constants
    use A_module
    integer :: k

    do  k = 1,10000
        call A 
    end do

end program main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Definite an `init_a_matrix` subroutine that initializes the matrix outside of the do loop.

```
subroutine init_a_matrix
   ! Do initialization here
end subroutine init_a_matrix
```

Then you have

```
call init_a_matrix
do  k = 1,10000
    call A 
end do
```

---

If you want to eliminate the redundant initialization of `myMatrix` in the subroutine A (since it only needs to be calculated once, upon the initial call of the subroutine), you can use the `SAVE` attribute and a `LOGICAL` flag.  In subroutine `A` you do,

```
logical :: init_flag = .false.
real, save :: matrix_a(n,n)
if (init_flag .eqv. .false.) then
   ! Initialize matrix_a on the first call to the subroutine and reset init_flag.
   init_flag = .true.
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

If `myMatrix` is an *unsaved*, *local* variable of the subroutine `A`, then it will be necessary to recalculate its values on each entry of the subroutine: unsaved local variables become undefined when the subroutine completes execution.

However, there are a number of approaches to reuse the variable:

- make it a *saved* local variable: saved local variables retain their definition
- have it as a dummy argument, not a local variable (argument association): its definition comes from the caller
- have it as some other form of non-local variable (other [forms of association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397539/3157076)): its definition comes from another place

If it's a saved variable, compute it on the first entry to the subroutine and retains its definition on subsequent calls:

```
subroutine A
  <declaration>, save :: mymatrix
  logical, save :: first_entry = .TRUE.

  if (first_entry) then
     ! set up mymatrix
     first_entry = .FALSE.
  end if
  ! ...
end subroutine A
```

You can do much the same with `mymatrix` a module/host variable. You can either use the `first_entry` saved indicator or rely on the user (as in [evets's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855217/3157076)) having an extra setup step:

```
module A_module
use constants
<declaration> myMatrix  ! Example with host association, automatically saved
contains
    subroutine A
    ! myMatrix is reused, either set up by a distinct call or on first entry
    ! other steps that use myMatrix
    end subroutine A
end module A_module
```

Or you can have the variable as a dummy argument:

```
mymatrix_actual = ...
do k = 1,10000
  call A(mymatrix_actual)  ! A now has the dummy variable
end do
```