# Initialization of 2d arrays within subroutines

Tags: fortran, fortran90

This is a follow-up question to a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62855189/758077) of mine regarding a Fortran 90 program.

I am using some Fortran-depended software that I need to write a Fortran file (only) consisting of subroutines. The subroutines I wrote will then be called repeatedly by the software to generate a result.

My subroutine file is of the following structure:

```
module constants
    integer :: N
end module constans

module A_module
use constants
contains
    subroutine A
    ! compute the 2D real array myMatrix(1:N,1:N)
    ! other steps that use myMatrix
    end subroutine A
end module A_module
```

The subroutine above will be called by some main program of the software, which I do **not** have access to edit:

```
program main
    use constants
    use A_module
    integer :: k

    do  k = 1,10000
        call A 
    end do

end program main
```

The problem is, again, the redundancy of initialization of `myMatrix` in the subroutine A: every time the subroutine is called, the matrix will be calculated again. But it only needs to be calculated once. Without touching the main program, namely, providing that one cannot write a line of initialization outside the loop of the main program, is there a way to get around this? (A confirmation that one cannot do this would be also a satisfying answer.)