# Pointers in Fortran Common Blocks

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm unexperienced in Fortran.  I'm trying to declare a memory pointer in a file named 'common', then allocate memory for that pointer in a file named "main.f", then call a subroutine from another file named "PrintArray.f".  The whole thing seg faults in "PrintArray.f".  How can I correct this?

This is the file named 'common':

```
REAL, DIMENSION (:), POINTER :: p_dynamicArray
```

This is the first Fortran file (main.f):

```
  PROGRAM Main
  include 'common'
  INTEGER :: ArraySize, i
  ArraySize = 4

  ALLOCATE (p_dynamicArray(ArraySize))

  DO i = 1, ArraySize
      p_dynamicArray(i) = i
  END DO

  call PrintArray()

  DEALLOCATE (p_dynamicArray)
  END
```

This is the second Fortran file (PrintArray.f):

```
  subroutine PrintArray()
  include 'common'
  INTEGER :: i

  DO i = 1, 4
      WRITE(0,*) "PrintArray.f: ", p_dynamicArray(i)
  END DO

  end
```

Comment: If that is ALL that is in the file called "common" then subroutine PrintArray() uses a completely different version of p_dynamicArray ... which has NOT been allocated (so segfaults). Put your dynamic array in a module and "use" that module.

Comment: You are not using common blocks. You also shouldn't be, but if you think you are we can tell you why you aren't. If you don't think you are, we can tell you more detail on what is wrong.

Comment: I suggest reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146/3157076) and its answers.

Comment: Okay, I agree.  I'm not using common blocks in the above.  I named the file 'common', but that file was simply included.  It was not a common block.  I tried the solution below with modules and it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: BTW why are you using a pointer? A general rule of modern Fortran is never use a pointer when you can use an allocatable, which is almost always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"include" has never been part of the Fortran standard (WHOOPS - SORRY, THAT'S WRONG!) - but all that it would do is simply place the contents of the file into the source code at that place.

You are NOT using common blocks, so nothing is shared between program units - PrintArray would have a completely separate pointer variable to that in main, one that hadn't been allocated or set.

If you use modules to share data then you can do this:

```
MODULE modcommon
   REAL, DIMENSION (:), POINTER :: p_dynamicArray
END MODULE modcommon


PROGRAM Main
  USE modcommon                        ! Allows shared content
  implicit none
  INTEGER :: ArraySize, i
  ArraySize = 4

  ALLOCATE (p_dynamicArray(ArraySize))

  DO i = 1, ArraySize
      p_dynamicArray(i) = i
  END DO

  CALL PrintArray()

  DEALLOCATE (p_dynamicArray)
END PROGRAM Main


SUBROUTINE PrintArray()
  USE modcommon                        ! Allows shared content
  implicit none
  INTEGER :: i

  DO i = 1, 4
      WRITE(*,*) "PrintArray.f: ", p_dynamicArray(i)
  END DO
END SUBROUTINE PrintArray
```

You can break that up into source (.f90) files. Make sure the one containing the module is compiled first.

Comment: Cheers @francescalus - apparently "include" did make it official in Fortran 90: had been decidedly unofficial until then. I'd still go with using modules, though.

Comment: Before the standard `include` introduced in F90, a common practice was to use the C preprocessor `#include`

Comment: INCLUDE was a very common extension in pre-F90 compilers, and was part of MIL-STD-1753, as I discuss in https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2020/05/16/doctor-fortran-in-military-strength/