# What is the scope of variables in fortran subroutines?

Tags: fortran

Can a subroutine in Fortran modify a variable in the main program?  My variable that was changed in the subroutine of course revents back to its original value upon exiting the subroutine because I'm not specifing it properly. Basically I'm just trying to clean up my main logic into an chronlogical list of subroutines.

As a followup question -- Assuming that you can have subroutines that change a global variable in the main logic (aka. a subroutine that doesn't need to perameter pass), how do you avoid all the "doesn't have an implicit type" crap?

As an example... From what I read, variable 'stringvar' is local in the subroutine because I have it defined again in the subroutine itself. Hence the scope...

```
program subroutines
    implicit none
    character*20 :: stringvar

    stringvar='first'

    print *,stringvar

    call changstr

    print *,stringvar

end program


subroutine changstr()

  implicit none

  character*20 :: stringvar


  print *,'in sub'

  stringvar='second'

  print *,stringvar

  return

end subroutine changstr
```

But if I take the variable definition out of subroutine changstr, I get...

Error: Symbol 'stringvar' has no IMPLICIT type...

Comment: Sorry, the merge messed up the line breaks and I didn't notice.  Everything is really where it is supposed to be.

Comment: There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386146/3157076) a procedure can modify a variable in another scope. But your two `stringvar` variables are not in any way associated with each other.

Comment: In code you posted, `stringvar` is local to both the main program and the subroutine.  Changing the value in one does effect the value in the other.  Now, if you had placed the subroutine within the program unit as a contained subprogram, you would find that the declaration of `stringvar` in the subroutine blocks host association.  If you remove the declaration in the contained subroutine, then `stringvar` would be the variable from the program unit through host association (i.e., there is no error).  It that case, changing value in the subroutine would effect the value in the main program.

Comment: I guess my problem is I don't understand how to make the assignment in the global correctly in a subroutine.  (aka. passing without perimeters or something).  Taking "character*20 :: stringvar" out of the subroutine generates the implicit type error at the variable assignment in the subroutine. I guess I have some studying to do.

Comment: Fortran isn't C.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the scope of the variables is limited to the program unit where they are declared. In your example you have two independent program units (the main program and the subroutine), and the variables are local to each unit.

Then there are several situations where variables have a broader scope:

- If they are parts of common blocks (deprecated)
- Contained routines  have access to the variables declared in the container (which can be a module, the main program, or another routine); this is *host association**
- Module variables are accessible by the program units that use the module, unless they are declared as private to the module